# Load XML file into MySql

Tags: mysql, xml

I would like to load the following XML into the table I created.

```
CREATE TABLE tempfighters(
fighterId INTEGER auto_increment,
dateCreated TIMESTAMP,
dateUpdated TIMESTAMP,
id VARCHAR(300),
first_name VARCHAR (30),
last_name VARCHAR (30),
nick_name VARCHAR(30),
height INTEGER,
weight INTEGER,
reach INTEGER,
stance VARCHAR(100),
 constraint tempfighters_pk
PRIMARY KEY (fighterId)
 );

<profile generated="2016-02-23T23:44:08Z"     
xmlns="http://feed.elasticstats.com/schema/mma/v1/participants-profile.xsd">
<fighters>
<fighter id="01585452-852a-4b40-a6dc-fdd04279f02c" height="72" weight="170"       
   reach="" stance="" first_name="Sai" nick_name="The Boss" last_name="Wang">
  <record wins="6" losses="4" draws="1" no_contests="0"/>
  <born date="1988-01-16" country_code="UNK" country="Unknown" state=""      
   city=""/>
  <out_of country_code="UNK" country="Unknown" state="" city=""/>
```

My code is not working and I'm sure as to why

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE "c:\....."
INTO TABLE tempfighters(first_name, last_name, nick_name, height, weight,     reach, stance)
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY "<fighter>"
```

Am I not properly pointing to the attributes that are within "fighter"?  Do I need to adjust for "fighter" being a child node?

Comment: `load xml` only accepts very strict formats of xml. you can't use it to load/parse ANY generic xml: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html

Comment: Thank you Marc - What do you think the best route is to covert XML into a format that can be loaded into MySQL.